# Parse Weekday string into time.Weekday

Tags: string, go, time

I've came across a problem to convert a Day of Week string into a `time.Weekday` value. I couldn't find anything built into the `time` package.

Then I've written this simple function (that covers my needs):

```golang
var daysOfWeek = [...]string{
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
}

func parseWeekday(v string) (time.Weekday, error) {
    for i := range daysOfWeek {
        if daysOfWeek[i] == v {
            return time.Weekday(i), nil
        }
    }

    return time.Sunday, fmt.Errorf("invalid weekday '%s'", v)
}
```

Is there any other *recommended* or *more idiomatic* way to perform this conversion in Golang?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`timex.ParseWeekday()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/timex#ParseWeekday).

---

Yes, use a map instead of an array, so lookups are faster and more straight-forward:

```
var daysOfWeek = map[string]time.Weekday{
    "Sunday":    time.Sunday,
    "Monday":    time.Monday,
    "Tuesday":   time.Tuesday,
    "Wednesday": time.Wednesday,
    "Thursday":  time.Thursday,
    "Friday":    time.Friday,
    "Saturday":  time.Saturday,
}

func parseWeekday(v string) (time.Weekday, error) {
    if d, ok := daysOfWeek[v]; ok {
        return d, nil
    }

    return time.Sunday, fmt.Errorf("invalid weekday '%s'", v)
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Monday"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Friday"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("invalid"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playgorund](https://play.golang.org/p/W4X82slF3S0)):

```
Monday <nil>
Friday <nil>
Sunday invalid weekday 'invalid'
```

**Tip:**

You can even use a `for` loop to initialize safely the `daysOfWeek` map like this:

```
var daysOfWeek = map[string]time.Weekday{}

func init() {
    for d := time.Sunday; d <= time.Saturday; d++ {
        daysOfWeek[d.String()] = d
    }
}
```

Testing and output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8914_85NgOW).

Another nice property of this map-solution (compared to your array-solution) is that you may list additional valid values in the same map that may be parsed into `time.Weekday` without additional parsing code.

For example, let's also parse the 3-letter short weekday names into their `time.Weekday` equivalent, e.g. `"Mon"` to `time.Monday`.

This extension can be added with a simple loop:

```
var daysOfWeek = map[string]time.Weekday{}

func init() {
    for d := time.Sunday; d <= time.Saturday; d++ {
        name := d.String()
        daysOfWeek[name] = d
        daysOfWeek[name[:3]] = d
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Monday"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Friday"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Mon"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("Fri"))
fmt.Println(parseWeekday("invalid"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/D91e8He9QAN)):

```
Monday <nil>
Friday <nil>
Monday <nil>
Friday <nil>
Sunday invalid weekday 'invalid'
```

See similar question: [Get integer month value from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681199/get-integer-month-value-from-string/59681275#59681275)

Answer (score -1):

This looks to do it:

```
package main
import "time"

func parseWeekday(v string) (time.Weekday, error) {
   t, e := time.Parse("Monday 2", v + " 2")
   if e != nil { return 0, e }
   return t.Weekday(), nil
}

func main() {
   n, e := parseWeekday("Sunday")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(n == time.Sunday)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/time#Parse

Comment: This isn't working https://go.dev/play/p/yQCrJkjxVI2