# Get integer month value from string

Tags: string, go, time

I'm parsing a cron string from AWS that looks like this `cron(0 7 13 November ? 2019)`. Is there a clean way to go from `November` back to `11` using Go's built in types?  The `time.Month` type allows mapping `int` to `string`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do the reverse.  Am I missing something?  For now, I've written this to get a `map[string]int` that I'm using like this: `monthi := getMonths()[monthName]`.

```
func getMonths() map[string]int {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        month := time.Month(i).String()
        m[month] = i
    }
    return m
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`timex.ParseMonth()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/timex#ParseMonth).

---

That is currently the best approach.

Best would be to use a package level variable and populate the map only once.

And it's much cleaner and safer to do the population this way:

```
var months = map[string]time.Month{}

func init() {
    for i := time.January; i <= time.December; i++ {
        months[i.String()] = i
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
for _, s := range []string{"January", "December", "invalid"} {
    m := months[s]
    fmt.Println(int(m), m)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7OAbwhpmuRc)):

```
1 January
12 December
0 %!Month(0)
```

Note that this map has the flexibility that you may add short month names, mapping to the same month. E.g. you may also add `months["Jan"] = time.January`, so if your input is `"Jan"`, you would also be able to get `time.January`. This could easily be done by slicing the long name, in the same loop, for example:

```
for i := time.January; i <= time.December; i++ {
    name := i.String()
    months[name] = i
    months[name[:3]] = i
}
```

Also note that it's possible to use [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) to do the parsing where the layout string is `"January"`:

```
for _, s := range []string{"January", "December", "invalid"} {
    t, err := time.Parse("January", s)
    m := t.Month()
    fmt.Println(int(m), m, err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yhIce4YJGdH)):

```
1 January <nil>
12 December <nil>
1 January parsing time "invalid" as "January": cannot parse "invalid" as "January"
```

But the simple map lookup is superior to this in performance.

See similar question: [Parse Weekday string into time.Weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456226/parse-weekday-string-into-time-weekday/52456320#52456320)

Comment: Haha, I've been sitting here working with this question open on a second monitor seeing the edits roll through.  And now it's released in a utility!  I love SO...  Also, thanks for your help, and great work!