# Dynamically get the property of a package using a variable value in Go

Tags: go

I've slightly modified a very simple Switch example from "A Tour of Go" website:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    day := "Wednesday"
    fmt.Printf("When's %s?\n", day)
    today := time.Now().Weekday()
    switch time.Wednesday {
    case today + 0:
        fmt.Println("Today.")
    case today + 1:
        fmt.Println("Tomorrow.")
    case today + 2:
        fmt.Println("In two days.")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Too far away.")
    }
}
```

Instead of `time.Wednesday` I would like to use the value of `day` to fetch the `time.Weekday`. 
In Python/JS it would be `time[day]`. 
How does one do this in Go ?

Comment: In Go you can't do this. So the compiler can make optimizations if something is not referred to explicitly, it can be left out from the final binary.

Comment: See [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879748/golang-reflect-get-type-representation-from-name/40882963#40882963); [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875016/splitting-client-server-code/38875901#38875901); and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-functions-with-special-prefix-suffix/37384665#37384665).

Comment: I may be terribly misunderstanding the question, but what's wrong with having a map that is initialized on load? Like - `map[string]time.Weekday{"Monday": time.Monday, ...}`

Comment: `time` does not provide a `Parse` function for `Weekday`.

Comment: For parsing a weekday string into a `time.Weekday`, see [Parse Weekday string into time.Weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456226/parse-weekday-string-into-time-weekday/52456320#52456320).